# Holoviews - UsageError: Cell magic `%%opts` not found

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, holoviews

I have installed HoloViews using condo and have `import HoloViews as hv` in my notebook. But when I try to run a cell with `%%opts`, I am receiving the error message mentioned in the title.

I am using python notebook with python 3 kernel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you load the holoviews extension in the notebook like this:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
# OR hv.extension('matplotlib')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I feel so stupid to not see this !